# "Dynamic Type" Changing font size of the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I am changing text size in the button when user selects prefered text size in the settings. I am doing it like that:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

self.button.font = font;
```

It does work, but I get an error:

> font is deprecated:first deprecated in IOS 3.0

I wonder if there is another, more proper way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `self.button.titleLabel.font = font;` instead (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel)).

Answer (score 1):

Use

`self.button.titleLabel.font = font;`